# How to create a grouped table view with multiple cell types?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm not using a storyboard and it's iOS 6.

I get what to do when all the cells are the same type but I require a grouped table view with multiple types of cells. Just as an example, let's say the first cell needs to be `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, the second cell needs to be `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, and the third cell is a custom cell (a `UITableViewCell` subclass that has a xib so it can be used with `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Mostly I'm unsure of the best way to structure `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. But I'm not sure if I should register the custom cell or all of them.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a variable length table and a static table won't fill your needs? You mentioned having a separate XIB file for custom cell layouts. You can create custom cells in the same XIB as your table and set a reuse identifier there. It's easier and works for many cases. Do you have a special case where that wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @DBD I've edited the question to indicate that it's static. I don't think I'm struggling with where to set the reuse identifier for the custom cell but if that's the solution please elaborate.

Comment: @DBD Also, I'm using that custom cell in many other places so it's probably best that it has its own xib file. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path. Since your custom cell is being used in other places a xib is a great place to load it up from. As far as the implementation you could do something like this.

Assuming your tableview is 'static' and has three cells, you could register your custom nib in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *customCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:customCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomIdentifier"]
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier1"];

        if(cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                           reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier1"];
        }
    }
    /* Cell 2 ommited for brevity */
    else if(indexPath.row == 2) {

        //Just to demonstrate the tableview is returning the correct type of cell from the XIB
        CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomIdentifier"];
        cell = customCell;
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Finally in IB for the Xib, set the proper `Identifier` for the cell.

[image: Xib - Cell in IB]

**Update**

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];
    }
    else {

        //custom cell here
        //cell.textfield.text = @"blah blah";
    }
}
```

A configure cell method is somewhat of a convention for tableview cells put in place primarily with the [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and its [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) where its used)

It's just a convenient way to reset reused cells with the proper content, and make `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` easier to read. I even make multiple version of configureCell like `configureCustomCell1:atIndexPath` to increase readability even more.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, helpful! What is the advantage of setting the `Identifier` for the custom cell in the xib?

Comment: Can you also show the code for `configureCell:atIndexPath:`? I'm assuming its method signature looks like this: `- (UITableViewCell *)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Once in there how does the CustomCell know it's a CustomCell? Use a cast? What's the best way/place to do that?

Comment: Interesting question actually, why set the Identifier in IB? As far as I can tell in this situation you don't need to since you are using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. The tablview reuses those cells properly without the Identifier set. You would want to set that if you were using one of the various other older methods to fetch cells out of a xib. I'll update my answer shortly with the configureCell implementation.

Comment: I had to do this cast in configureCell:atIndexPath: `if (indexPath.section == sectionWithCustomCells) {CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)cell; ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static table you won't need reuse identifiers or anything else because no cell will ever get re-used. Just set the table to be "Static Cells" of style "Grouped" and set the number of sections you want. You can click on the "Table View Section" and set how many rows are in the section (and set any header/footer you might want).

[image: Storyboard Example]

Then configure the cells however you would like. You can either choose a default cell or make the cell "Custom" and drag UI components from the Object Library. You can set up `IBOutlets` or `IBActions` to components in a static table cells just like you would for components in a normal view.

[image: Configure Cell]

Comment: I'm not seeing `Content: Static Cells` or `Sections:` I'm not using a Storyboard. Is that the difference?

Comment: But could I use a storyboard for just this table view?

Comment: To create a static table you would need to use a Storyboard. You could create a storyboard with a single view controller in it easily, but you cannot have a view with no view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I'm reluctant to accept the answer because I'm hoping that someone can explain how to do this with just xibs.

Comment: That doesn't bother me in slightest. Sadly XIBs don't support static table views. You could create a XIB with a "view" that is your `UITableView` and more views which are your `UITableViewCells` and load them all up that way using the standard re-use system (even if none actually get re-used).